# How can I use get_template_part() for specific post using get_post() in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating my first wordpress theme.
I'm currently using loops and get_template_part() for displaying my post list like this:

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
}
```

this works great and is loading the content.php as template for post.

I want to display a specific post using get_template_part() at the end of the regular posts output.
I added this for displaying my post with Id 123 after my while loop:

```
get_post(123);
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

So the total code is:

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    if($post->ID != 123) // exclude Post 123 from output
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
}

get_post(123);
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

But this just repeats the last Entry from the regular loop.
Can anyone help?

Thanks and regards
Jan

Comment: Likely you can solve your problem with `setup_postdata`

Comment: Thanks naththedeveloper - that unfortunately didn't work. BUT I got it: the_post() generates an object wich is stored in $post automatically; get_post only returns that object. So my solution was $post = get_post(123) to store the oject in $post for further usage in my get_template_part.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the working solution:

```
global $post; 
$post = get_post(123); 
setup_postdata($post);
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata

Comment: Remember to reset with  `wp_reset_postdata();` when using `setup_postdata`. It  changes the global $post, and can give very weird errors. 
For example: I just used 2 hours trying to figure out why me trying to edit my frontpage opened up a product edit page. This was a missing `wp_reset_postdata()` fault.